# django celery-progress: default messages of element 'progress-bar-message' replace custom message

Tags: django, celery, progress-bar, celery-task

I start using Django celery-progress and have an issue with messages displayed while waiting for task to start

in my template, I have customized progress-bar-message element with an icon and changing text ***Waiting for progress to start...*** for ***Waiting for import to start...***:

```
<div id="progress-bar-message"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> Waiting for import to start...<span></div>
```

but even if my changes are displayed at start, it is change to ***Waiting for task to start...*** without icon...

I do not understand how to manage this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide an onProgress() function when creating your CeleryProgressBar in javascript.

By default, it calls [onProgressDefault()](https://github.com/czue/celery-progress/blob/4b1e023cbd72083e1eb542560c49d5653ceb5ee2/celery_progress/static/celery_progress/celery_progress.js#L72), which has that text hardcoded.  But it can be overridden with the user-provided [onProgress()](https://github.com/czue/celery-progress/blob/4b1e023cbd72083e1eb542560c49d5653ceb5ee2/celery_progress/static/celery_progress/celery_progress.js#L10)